# How do I clear a VisualForce form that connects to a custom controller after a successful submission?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VisualForce form with an Apex custom controller behind it that allows my users to create 3 different objects in succession. I want the form to be cleared after submission, so I tried using this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Create Enquiry" oncomplete="this.form.reset();return false;"/>
```

This calles the "save" function in my custom controller. While this does technically work, it means that when I click save, if any of the mandatory fields aren't filled up, or any field fails validation (e.g. email field), the form also gets cleared.
How can I get the form to clear only after submission was completed? Is there a way to do from within the custom controller, bearing in mind the fields on the form come from 3 different objects (in case that matters).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual answer is to reset the objects you use in the controller then return null, in order to arrive at the same page with empty fields. Without seeing your controller, I can really only guess, so heres some pseudocode:

```
public sObject someObject { get; set; } 

public PageReference Save() {

    try {
        insert someObject; // mixed or multiple dml statements 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(e);
        return null; 
    }

    ResetObjects(); 

    return null; 
}

private void ResetObjects() {
    someObject = new sObject(); 

    // set defaults, etc.. 
}
```

---

That being said, resetting the form after saving a record would be confusing to me as a user - at least without some kind of confirmation that the last record was created successfully, and that the now blank page is for creating another record. Maybe split your buttons, and match the salesforce standard behavior - "Save" and "Save & Create New Record"?

Comment: Thanks! Currently when saving is completed, I do show a message using ApexPages.AddMessage, but all the fields contain the previous data, which also I find a bit annoying. From your suggestion does it mean that I'll need to reset each object/field?
Also, my save is a void method, not PageReference, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: Reset each object. Setting the object to a new instance is the easy way to do it, but you can also set each field to a default, or any other value. Resetting the object empties all the fields & ids.  I usually add the` return PageReference` explicitly for save methods since it aligns with the standard behavior (`StandardController.Save()` returns a pagereference with the resulting page, its usually what I return when using a standard controller). It doesn't really make a difference, I think apex knows to rerender from the rerender attribute.

Comment: Great! Changed my code accordingly, now it saves and returns with a message and a clear slate.
Many thanks!